# Field with cyclic product group

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, fields, finite-fields

If a field has a cyclic multiplicative group, is it necessarily finite?

Comment: Is the product group the same as the  multiplicative group (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group)?

Comment: Yes, it has been edited.

Comment: Do you mean:
If a field *is* cyclic as a multiplicative group..., or
If a field *has* a cyclic multiplicative *sub*group?


Comment: It wouldn't be good to use the first expression, since the multiplicative group excludes an element of the underlying set.  $ \;  $  If the field has a cyclic multiplicative group, then the field's multiplicative group is cyclic, since the field has a unique multiplicative group (namely, it's multiplicative group).

Answer (score 9):

Yes; it suffices to rule out that the multiplicative group is $\mathbb{Z}$.  The field can't have characteristic zero, since $\mathbb{Q}^\times$ is not finitely generated (so not contained in $\mathbb{Z}$).  If it has characteristic $p \neq 2$, then it contains $\mathbb{F}_p$, where $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$ has torsion of order greater than 2 and so is also not contained in $\mathbb{Z}$.  If $p = 2$, then the field can't contain $\mathbb{F}_4$ for the same reason, so if it's not $\mathbb{F}_2$, it must be transcendental over it.  But $\mathbb{F}_2(x)^\times$ is not finitely generated again, so not contained in $\mathbb{Z}$ either.

Comment: The same argument proves the stronger claim that, if the multiplicative group is finitely generated then the field is finite.

Answer (score 9):

Assume that the elements of field $F$ are 0, ${a^n}$.

Case 1: If the characteristic is not 2. Then$1 \ne  - 1$, therefore$ - 1 = {a^n}(n \ne 0)$ and ${a^{2n}} = 1$. Hence we conclude that it is finite.

Case 2: If the characteristic is 2. First we have $1 + a = {a^s}$and we can assume that $s \ne 1$ , otherwise the field is trivial. Then we conclude that $a$ is algebraic over ${F_2}$and ${\rm{ F= }}{F_2}(a)$. We can set the degree of the minimal polynomial of is n , then all the elements of $F$ can be written as a linear combination of $1,a,{a^2} \cdots {a^{n - 1}}$over${F_2}$ , but the cardinal number of all such element is finite, which concludes the proof.

Answer (score 3):

The following proof is a short proof of the stronger claim stated by @Gjergji-Zaimi :

The main ingredient is the fact that if finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra is a field, then it is a finite field. (this is essentially equivalent to Nullstellensatz).

If the multiplicative group of a field $F$ is finitely generated then $F$ would be a finitely generetad $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra, hence $F$ is a finite field.